# Learning how to use Clojure (Language) with Closure (Google Library)

Tags: clojure, closures

I've gone through the Ring/Enlive tutorials. I'm trying to pick up the rest of the Clojure webstack by learning how to use Google Closure with Clojure. So far, I have the Google Closure book (but haven't read it yet). What are the good resources for learning the Clojure/Closure webstack?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use clojure on the client (clojurescript) too (and it probably makes sense to do so, because it has very tight integration with closure) then you need to download + play with [clojurescript one](http://clojurescriptone.com/).

it's a complete example (server + client) that you can pull apart and play with.